# Using .includes method in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a an object `jsonRes[0]` containing values which need to be removed based on a condition.  The following works to remove `null`,  missing values and those equal to zero in the stringified object:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
          // Filtering out properties
          if (value === null || value === 0 || value === "") {
            return undefined;
          }
          return value;
        } 

JSON.stringify(jsonRes[0], replacer, "\t")
```

However, when I add a condition using the the `includes` method, I receive an error:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
          // Filtering out properties
          if (value === null || value === 0 || value === "" || value.includes("$")) {
            return undefined;
          }
          return value;
        } 


Uncaught TypeError: value.includes is not a function
```

Why is this the case and is there a workaround?

Comment: if the value is undefined, means it does'nt has anything like includes function

Comment: If you look at the documentation of includes() :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes, most of the browsers don't support this property.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340868/includes-not-working-in-all-browsers
You can use widely supported indexOf() after converting the property to string using toString():

Comment: Well, if `value` is a number, (non-array) object or boolean, it won't have an `.includes` method? Presumably you meant to write something like `typeof value == "string" && value.includes("$")`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), As it is available in ES6 and not supported in IE at all.

```
typeof value == "string" && value.indexOf('$') > -1
```

Also note if `value` is not string type it will still raise an error `boolean`, `Number` doesn't the the method. You can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to validate whether `value` is a string.

Answer (score 16):

The `.includes()` API is part of the `String` and `Array` data type.

So what the error is trying to tell you is that the value for variable `value`, e.g. an integer or object, does not have the property `.includes`.

You could do checks like

1. `typeof a_string === 'string'`
2. `an_array instanceof Array`

before the `.includes()` api to prevent this.

Obviously this will make your if statement rather ugly due to the number of checks you have.

Based on the way your code is written I suspect you are more interested in checking "String" than array. So **becareful** of arrays. Your code may not work properly if it is array.

Anyway here is a refractored version of your code.

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
   // Filtering out properties
   if (!value || typeof value === "string" && value.includes("$")) {
        return undefined;
   }
   return value;
 } 

console.log("NULL returns:" + replacer('test', null));
console.log("$Test returns:" + replacer('test', '$test'));
console.log("Blah returns:" + replacer('test', 'Blah'));
```

Comment: This answer should be part of second part of accepted answer. 'also note ...'

Answer (score 6):

Just one more possibility: Maybe your `value` is not a string type object.

`(typeof(value) == "string" &&  value.includes("$"))`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error, which I was getting when applying "includes" to a "window.location" value, by appending ".toString();"

var requestUrl = window.location.toString();

if (requestUrl.includes(urlBase + "#")) {
...

Answer (score 0):

I actually am not sure what type of the variable named `value` is, but anyway, `Array.prototype.includes` and `String.prototype.includes` are only available in ES6. You need to use `babel-polyfill` or any other bundling modules like `rollup.js`, `webpack` with babel or something like that to use `includes` function.