# Javascript: Filter elements parts in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to select all the elements in an Array that contain the word "Orange", independently of the number before.

I tried with this code, but it is only working when I write the exact element name like "02orange".

```
var DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"];

function checkOrange(orange) {
    return orange == "02orange";
}
var OrangeArray = DWArray.filter(checkOrange);
return OrangeArray.join(", ");
```

**My desired result is:**

`["02orange", "03orange", "04orange"];`

Comment: I suggest that you google "javascript string". The first hit is the MDN documentation which has a list of available methods. Look through this list and find one that does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the result of the check with [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
function checkOrange(orange) {
    return orange.includes("orange");
}

var DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"],
    OrangeArray = DWArray.filter(checkOrange);

console.log(OrangeArray.join(", "));
```

For older Browser, you might use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
function checkOrange(orange) {
    return orange.indexOf("orange") !== -1;
}

var DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"],
    OrangeArray = DWArray.filter(checkOrange);

console.log(OrangeArray.join(", "));
```

Comment: I tried Includes but I have this error all the time "orange.includes is not a function in <eval>", that is why I used filter instead

Comment: do you use an older browser?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor and `RegExp.prototype.test()` with string `"orange"` passed as first parameter and `i` (ignore case; if u flag is also enabled, use Unicode case folding) and `g` flags (global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match) passed as second parameter

```js
var DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"];

function checkOrange(orange) {
  return new RegExp("orange", "ig").test(orange)
}

var OrangeArray = DWArray.filter(checkOrange);

console.log(OrangeArray, OrangeArray.join(", "));
```

Comment: Using RegExp I get this error: "cannot supply flags when constructing one regexp from another". Do you know why? Thank you

Comment: @Kayra See updated post. Should be a string passed as first parameter to `RegExp` constructor

Comment: Is the `g` flag really useful since the OP only needs to know if the word contains `orange` ? +1 for the `i` flag though

Answer (score 0):

Use `.includes` to check if the string includes orange in it, with filter. [Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

```js
var DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"];
console.log(DWArray.filter(e=>e.includes('orange')))
```

Comment: when I use "Includes" I get this error "orange.includes is not a function in <eval>", that is why I used filter instead. Do you know why? Thank you

Comment: You might find the answer to that here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820770/using-includes-method-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex and `RegExp.test()` in one line:

```js
const DWArray = ["apple", "apple", "02orange", "03orange", "04orange", "potato"];
const OrangeArray = DWArray.filter(s => /orange/i.test(s)).join(', ');

console.log(OrangeArray);
```